# Getting null in HttpServletRequest object, when i am hitting from postman

Tags: java

I am getting null in params, when i am hitting post request from postman,
but code is working when i am posting data from my application.

below  is code for the same.

```
public class demoController {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    @Inject
    UpiService service;

    @GET
    @Path(value = "/start")
    public String getData() {
        return "UPI Simulator Started";
    }


    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response delegate() throws Exception {
        List<String> parameterNamesList = Collections.list(request.getParameterNames());
        String params = parameterNamesList.toString();
    }
```

Comment: probably you are not doing a 'POST' request ;)

Comment: please you check your network tab and see the request payload for application submit. then, follow the same payload for postman. may be your postman request is deference from application submit.